# Run laravel on remote server

Tags: php, laravel

I installed laravel by command `composer global require "laravel/installer"` and created project `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`.

In folder `public_html` I left only folder `public` and all another i moved to a level higher. Also i changed:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

To:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But when i go to `my_domain.com/public/` my page is empty. What i did wrong? I use Apache HTTP Server

Also i have this two errors, but don't know fix it. I think my requires are right

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/kurusa/web/my_domain/public_html/public/vendor       /autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kurusa/web/my_domain/public_html/public/index.php on line 24

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/kurusa/web/my_domain/public_html/public/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/remi/php71/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/remi/php71/root/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/kurusa/web/my_domain/public_html/public/index.php on line 24
```

Comment: is there no error ? just a blank page ? try the hostaddress/index.php

Comment: @Demonyowhhave already tried my_domain/index.php - nothing, blank page. I edited my question and added errors - maybe, you can help?

Comment: is it correct that your `laravel_framework_folder` is in the same level with the `public_html folder` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my understanding you left the `public` directory in the `public_html` and the rest was moved up a higher level directory .. so currently your folder structure should be like this ..

1.) /laravel_framework

2.) /public_html

3.) /public_html/public

from

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

it should be

```
require __DIR__.'../../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'../../bootstrap/app.php';
```

this is because the vendor `autoload.php` and the `app.php` moved a higher level not on the same level with the `index.php`